# Send data from websocket to front end - Nodejs, Expressjs

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, handlebars.js, trading

I'm working on a project that uses the binance api to create an interface to make day trading cryptos easier.

The call to their api looks like this:

```
binance.websockets.candlesticks(['BNBBTC'], "1m", function(candlesticks) {
    let { e:eventType, E:eventTime, s:symbol, k:ticks } = candlesticks;
    let { o:open, h:high, l:low, c:close, v:volume, n:trades, i:interval, x:isFinal, q:quoteVolume, V:buyVolume, Q:quoteBuyVolume } = ticks;
    console.log(symbol+" "+interval+" candlestick update");
    console.log("open: "+open);
    console.log("high: "+high);
    console.log("low: "+low);
    console.log("close: "+close);
    console.log("volume: "+volume);
    console.log("isFinal: "+isFinal);
  });
```

It seems to be returning data at a fixed interval, so I'm skeptical as to whether it's actually *real time*, but regardless, I'm wondering how to send this data to the front end as it comes in.

Currently, I'm doing this with the static data:

```
router.get('/interface', function(req,res) {
    binance.candlesticks("BNBBTC", "5m", function(ticks, symbol) {
        console.log("candlesticks()", ticks);
        let last_tick = ticks[ticks.length - 1];
        let [time, open, high, low, close, volume, closeTime, assetVolume, trades, buyBaseVolume, buyAssetVolume, ignored] = last_tick;
        console.log(symbol+" last close: "+close);
        res.render('interface', {ticks:ticks});
    });
  });
```

I've messed with socket.io in the past, but am unsure how to utilize it. Any help would be much appreciated! And please hmu if you're interested in cryptos. We are putting together a group in discord to share our research, and trading strategies.

Answer (score 0):

To initiate the data sending process from the backend, (instead of frontend requesting data), you should use websockets (socketIO as you have mentioned).

To do that, first, you should start a socketio server in your express app, by wrapping the http/https server or express app.

Then, from the frontend, you should initiate a socketio-client.

Next, your frontend client should establish a connection with the server using the connect method of the socketio-client. It will fire an event in the server, with the socket connection.

Finally, the server can use that socket connection, to send any amount of data to the client. (You might need to save the connection for latter use).

Comment: thanks! could you elaborate a bit on how that communication might look?

Comment: Is it something like this:

`router.get('interface', function(req,res) {
  binance.websocket.candlesticks(function(ticks) {
    socket.on(ticks, socket.emit(ticks))
  })
})`

Comment: You don't need a router. Everything should be done with socketIO. By any chance, do you want to initiate the communication from the frontend (from a button click, page load, etc)?

Comment: makes sense. I just want to start retrieving data on page load

Comment: If that's the case, you don't need websockets. However, you will need to persist the data received in realtime from the binance socket to some database like mongodb, redis or application state.
Then from the HTTP request, you just need to query the storage and respond.

Comment: IMO You need websockets only if you want the page to get updated with the values, without the user refreshing the page

Answer (score 0):

i'm trying to do basically the same thing, what discord group you talking about?

Comment: send me an email - mna271@nyu.edu
haven't formally put it together yet, but will focus on this project all weekend.